# C# RSA encryption/decryption with transmission

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa

I've seen plenty of encryption/decryption tutorials and examples on the net in C# that use the System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider, but what I'm hoping to be able to do is:

- Create an RSA public/private keypair
- Transmit the public key (or for proof of concept, just move it in a string variable)
- Create a new RSA crypto provider and encrypt a string with the public key
- Transmit the encrypted string (or data) back to the original crypto provider and decrypt the string

Could anyone point me to a useful resource for this?

Comment: Could you point out a specific tutorial that explains encryption and decryption with RSA in C# that does not address your specific needs? I'd say they are pretty straightforward, and it's not clear to me from your question, what part you are having a problem with.

Comment: Also on the bullet #1, what would be the best practice of storing the private key in a local store/container on the machine where data will eventually gets decrypted.

Comment: Warning: I would not consider any of the given answers using good practice. Please refactor, look into hybrid cryptosystems and don't simply copy any of these answers into your code. Static keys, always encoded to XML which is not standard practice. Not using OAEP but keeping to PKCS#1 encryption. Too small key sizes. Using `Unicode` to encode text, etc. etc.

Comment: From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): `Questions asking us to recommend or find [an] off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow`.

Answer (score 273, accepted):

well there are really enough examples for this, but anyway,  here you go

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace RsaCryptoExample
{
  static class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      //lets take a new CSP with a new 2048 bit rsa key pair
      var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);

      //how to get the private key
      var privKey = csp.ExportParameters(true);

      //and the public key ...
      var pubKey = csp.ExportParameters(false);

      //converting the public key into a string representation
      string pubKeyString;
      {
        //we need some buffer
        var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        //we need a serializer
        var xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
        //serialize the key into the stream
        xs.Serialize(sw, pubKey);
        //get the string from the stream
        pubKeyString = sw.ToString();
      }

      //converting it back
      {
        //get a stream from the string
        var sr = new System.IO.StringReader(pubKeyString);
        //we need a deserializer
        var xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
        //get the object back from the stream
        pubKey = (RSAParameters)xs.Deserialize(sr);
      }

      //conversion for the private key is no black magic either ... omitted

      //we have a public key ... let's get a new csp and load that key
      csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
      csp.ImportParameters(pubKey);

      //we need some data to encrypt
      var plainTextData = "foobar";

      //for encryption, always handle bytes...
      var bytesPlainTextData = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainTextData);

      //apply pkcs#1.5 padding and encrypt our data 
      var bytesCypherText = csp.Encrypt(bytesPlainTextData, false);

      //we might want a string representation of our cypher text... base64 will do
      var cypherText = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesCypherText);


      /*
       * some transmission / storage / retrieval
       * 
       * and we want to decrypt our cypherText
       */

      //first, get our bytes back from the base64 string ...
      bytesCypherText = Convert.FromBase64String(cypherText);

      //we want to decrypt, therefore we need a csp and load our private key
      csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
      csp.ImportParameters(privKey);

      //decrypt and strip pkcs#1.5 padding
      bytesPlainTextData = csp.Decrypt(bytesCypherText, false);

      //get our original plainText back...
      plainTextData = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytesPlainTextData);
    }
  }
}
```

as a side note: the calls to Encrypt() and Decrypt() have a bool parameter that switches between OAEP and PKCS#1.5 padding ... you might want to choose OAEP if it's available in your situation

Comment: This way the cypherText gets very long! Is there any algorithm to shorten it while having the same security? (And preferably containing only digits and uppercase letters)

Comment: @SepehrM RSA is not intended to encrypt large amounts of data ... you should possibly consider using a symetric cipher like AES or Twofish for your data, and RSA (or another asymetric cipher) for encryption of your symetric key ... hybrid crypto ...

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 That, BTW was the way WannaCry managed to encrypt the files  so fast.

Comment: Microsoft's Example keeps throwing errors on decrypt, but your example after I tore it apart, works perfectly..  Thanks.

Comment: I know its been a few years, but to add to SepehrM's discussion, RSA is intended to be super secure but primarily for encrypting a client's public key (key exchange) so that a server can encrypt large payloads with that key using a different algorithm.

Answer (score 19):

```
public static string Encryption(string strText)
        {
            var publicKey = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>21wEnTU+mcD2w0Lfo1Gv4rtcSWsQJQTNa6gio05AOkV/Er9w3Y13Ddo5wGtjJ19402S71HUeN0vbKILLJdRSES5MHSdJPSVrOqdrll/vLXxDxWs/U0UT1c8u6k/Ogx9hTtZxYwoeYqdhDblof3E75d9n2F0Zvf6iTb4cI7j6fMs=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";

            var testData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strText);

            using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024))
            {
                try
                {
                    // client encrypting data with public key issued by server                    
                    rsa.FromXmlString(publicKey.ToString());

                    var encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(testData, true);

                    var base64Encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);

                    return base64Encrypted;
                }
                finally
                {
                    rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
                }
            }
        }

        public static string Decryption(string strText)
        {
            var privateKey = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>21wEnTU+mcD2w0Lfo1Gv4rtcSWsQJQTNa6gio05AOkV/Er9w3Y13Ddo5wGtjJ19402S71HUeN0vbKILLJdRSES5MHSdJPSVrOqdrll/vLXxDxWs/U0UT1c8u6k/Ogx9hTtZxYwoeYqdhDblof3E75d9n2F0Zvf6iTb4cI7j6fMs=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>/aULPE6jd5IkwtWXmReyMUhmI/nfwfkQSyl7tsg2PKdpcxk4mpPZUdEQhHQLvE84w2DhTyYkPHCtq/mMKE3MHw==</P><Q>3WV46X9Arg2l9cxb67KVlNVXyCqc/w+LWt/tbhLJvV2xCF/0rWKPsBJ9MC6cquaqNPxWWEav8RAVbmmGrJt51Q==</Q><DP>8TuZFgBMpBoQcGUoS2goB4st6aVq1FcG0hVgHhUI0GMAfYFNPmbDV3cY2IBt8Oj/uYJYhyhlaj5YTqmGTYbATQ==</DP><DQ>FIoVbZQgrAUYIHWVEYi/187zFd7eMct/Yi7kGBImJStMATrluDAspGkStCWe4zwDDmdam1XzfKnBUzz3AYxrAQ==</DQ><InverseQ>QPU3Tmt8nznSgYZ+5jUo9E0SfjiTu435ihANiHqqjasaUNvOHKumqzuBZ8NRtkUhS6dsOEb8A2ODvy7KswUxyA==</InverseQ><D>cgoRoAUpSVfHMdYXW9nA3dfX75dIamZnwPtFHq80ttagbIe4ToYYCcyUz5NElhiNQSESgS5uCgNWqWXt5PnPu4XmCXx6utco1UVH8HGLahzbAnSy6Cj3iUIQ7Gj+9gQ7PkC434HTtHazmxVgIR5l56ZjoQ8yGNCPZnsdYEmhJWk=</D></RSAKeyValue>";

            var testData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strText);

            using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024))
            {
                try
                {                    
                    var base64Encrypted = strText;

                    // server decrypting data with private key                    
                    rsa.FromXmlString(privateKey);

                    var resultBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Encrypted);
                    var decryptedBytes = rsa.Decrypt(resultBytes, true);
                    var decryptedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);
                    return decryptedData.ToString();
                }
                finally
                {
                    rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: how did you generate the keys

Comment: @Sana You can get the keys using `ToXmlString` method. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16712348/7196681).

Comment: What are the values for the values except `Modulus`, if the keys are generated via https://cryptotools.net/rsagen?

Answer (score 6):

Honestly, I have difficulty implementing it because there's barely any tutorials I've searched that displays writing the keys into the files. The accepted answer was "fine". But for me I had to improve it so that both keys gets saved into two separate files. I've written a helper class so y'all just gotta copy and paste it. Hope this helps lol.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace RsaCryptoExample
{
    class RSAFileHelper
    {
        readonly string pubKeyPath = "public.key";//change as needed
        readonly string priKeyPath = "private.key";//change as needed
        public void MakeKey()
        {
            //lets take a new CSP with a new 2048 bit rsa key pair
            RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);

            //how to get the private key
            RSAParameters privKey = csp.ExportParameters(true);

            //and the public key ...
            RSAParameters pubKey = csp.ExportParameters(false);
            //converting the public key into a string representation
            string pubKeyString;
            {
                //we need some buffer
                var sw = new StringWriter();
                //we need a serializer
                var xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
                //serialize the key into the stream
                xs.Serialize(sw, pubKey);
                //get the string from the stream
                pubKeyString = sw.ToString();
                File.WriteAllText(pubKeyPath, pubKeyString);
            }
            string privKeyString;
            {
                //we need some buffer
                var sw = new StringWriter();
                //we need a serializer
                var xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
                //serialize the key into the stream
                xs.Serialize(sw, privKey);
                //get the string from the stream
                privKeyString = sw.ToString();
                File.WriteAllText(priKeyPath, privKeyString);
            }
        }
        public void EncryptFile(string filePath)
        {
            //converting the public key into a string representation
            string pubKeyString;
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pubKeyPath)){pubKeyString = reader.ReadToEnd();}
            }
            //get a stream from the string
            var sr = new StringReader(pubKeyString);

            //we need a deserializer
            var xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));

            //get the object back from the stream
            RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            csp.ImportParameters((RSAParameters)xs.Deserialize(sr));
            byte[] bytesPlainTextData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

            //apply pkcs#1.5 padding and encrypt our data 
            var bytesCipherText = csp.Encrypt(bytesPlainTextData, false);
            //we might want a string representation of our cypher text... base64 will do
            string encryptedText = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesCipherText);
            File.WriteAllText(filePath,encryptedText);
        }
        public void DecryptFile(string filePath)
        {
            //we want to decrypt, therefore we need a csp and load our private key
            RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

            string privKeyString;
            {
                privKeyString = File.ReadAllText(priKeyPath);
                //get a stream from the string
                var sr = new StringReader(privKeyString);
                //we need a deserializer
                var xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
                //get the object back from the stream
                RSAParameters privKey = (RSAParameters)xs.Deserialize(sr);
                csp.ImportParameters(privKey);
            }
            string encryptedText;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath)) { encryptedText = reader.ReadToEnd(); }
            byte[] bytesCipherText = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);

            //decrypt and strip pkcs#1.5 padding
            byte[] bytesPlainTextData = csp.Decrypt(bytesCipherText, false);

            //get our original plainText back...
            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytesPlainTextData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you use XmlSerializer?

Answer (score 0):

I'll share my very simple code for sample purpose. Hope it will help someone like me searching for quick code reference.
My goal was to receive rsa signature from backend, then validate against input string using public key and store locally for future periodic verifications. 
Here is main part used for signature verification:

```
        ...
        var signature = Get(url); // base64_encoded signature received from server
        var inputtext= "inputtext"; // this is main text signature was created for
        bool result = VerifySignature(inputtext, signature);
        ...

    private bool VerifySignature(string input, string signature)
    {
        var result = false;
        using (var cps=new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            // converting input and signature to Bytes Arrays to pass to VerifyData rsa method to verify inputtext was signed using privatekey corresponding to public key we have below
            byte[] inputtextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
            byte[] signatureBytes  = Convert.FromBase64String(signature);

            cps.FromXmlString("<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>....</Modulus><Exponent>....</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>"); // xml formatted publickey
            result = cps.VerifyData(inputtextBytes , new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(), signatureBytes  );
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for big data

```
public class RsaService : System.IDisposable
{
public delegate int TransformBlockCall(System.ReadOnlySpan<byte> data, System.Span<byte> destination);

private readonly RSA _encoder;
private readonly RSAEncryptionPadding _padding;

private readonly TransformBlockCall _encryptBlockCall;
private readonly TransformBlockCall _decryptBlockCall;

private int _encrypt_InputBlockSize;
private int _encrypt_OutputBlockSize;
private int _decrypt_InputBlockSize;
private int _decrypt_OutputBlockSize;

public RsaService(RSA encoder) {
    if(encoder == null)
        throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(encoder));
    _encoder = encoder;

    _padding = RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1;

    _encryptBlockCall = new TransformBlockCall(EncryptBlock);
    _decryptBlockCall = new TransformBlockCall(DecryptBlock);

    OnEndSetParameters();
}

private void OnEndSetParameters() {
    _encrypt_InputBlockSize = GetSizeOutputEncryptOfKeySize(_encoder.KeySize);
    _encrypt_OutputBlockSize = _encoder.KeySize / 8;
    _decrypt_InputBlockSize = _encrypt_OutputBlockSize;
    _decrypt_OutputBlockSize = _encrypt_OutputBlockSize;
}

public void ImportParameters(RSAParameters parameters) {
    _encoder.ImportParameters(parameters);
    OnEndSetParameters();
}

public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data) {
    if(data == null) throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));
    if(data.Length == 0) return data;
    int outputLength = GetEncryptOutputMaxByteCount(data.Length);
    byte[] outputData = new byte[outputLength];
    Encrypt(data, outputData);
    return outputData;
}


public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data) {
    if(data == null) throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));
    if(data.Length == 0) return data;
    int maxOutputLength = GetDecryptOutputMaxByteCount(data.Length);
    byte[] outputData = new byte[maxOutputLength];
    int actual_OutputLength = Decrypt(data, outputData);
    if(maxOutputLength > actual_OutputLength)
        System.Array.Resize(ref outputData, actual_OutputLength);
    return outputData;
}

public int Encrypt(System.ReadOnlySpan<byte> data, System.Span<byte> destination) {
#if DEBUG
    int inputBlockSize = _encrypt_InputBlockSize;
    int outputBlockSize = _encoder.KeySize / 8;
    int blockCount = (data.Length / inputBlockSize);
    if(data.Length % inputBlockSize != 0)
        blockCount++;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert((blockCount * outputBlockSize) <= destination.Length);
#endif

    if(data.Length > _encrypt_InputBlockSize)
        return TransformFinal(_encryptBlockCall, data, destination, _encrypt_InputBlockSize);
    else
        return _encryptBlockCall(data, destination);
}


public int Decrypt(System.ReadOnlySpan<byte> data, System.Span<byte> destination) {
    if(data.Length > _decrypt_InputBlockSize)
        return TransformFinal(_decryptBlockCall, data, destination, _decrypt_InputBlockSize);
    else
        return _decryptBlockCall(data, destination);
}

private int EncryptBlock(System.ReadOnlySpan<byte> data, System.Span<byte> destination) => _encoder.Encrypt(data, destination, _padding);
private int DecryptBlock(System.ReadOnlySpan<byte> data, System.Span<byte> destination) => _encoder.Decrypt(data, destination, _padding);

public int GetEncryptOutputMaxByteCount(int inputCount) => GetBlockCount(inputCount, _encrypt_InputBlockSize) * _encrypt_OutputBlockSize;
public int GetDecryptOutputMaxByteCount(int inputCount) => GetBlockCount(inputCount, _decrypt_InputBlockSize) * _decrypt_OutputBlockSize;
public void Dispose() {
    _encoder.Dispose();
    System.GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}


#region Methods_Helper

public static RsaService Create(RSAParameters parameters) => new RsaService(RSA.Create(parameters));

public static RsaService Create() => new RsaService(RSA.Create());

// [keySize] ÷ 8 - [11 bytes for padding] = Result
// Exsimple: [2048 key size] ÷ 8 - [11 bytes for padding] = 245
public static int GetSizeOutputEncryptOfKeySize(int keySize) => (keySize / 8) - 11;

private static int GetBlockCount(int dataLength,int inputBlockSize) {
    int blockCount = (dataLength / inputBlockSize);
    if(dataLength % inputBlockSize != 0)
        blockCount++;
    return blockCount;
}

public static int TransformFinal(TransformBlockCall transformBlockCall, System.ReadOnlySpan<byte> data, System.Span<byte> destination, int inputBlockSize) {

    int blockCount = GetBlockCount(data.Length, inputBlockSize);

    int data_writtenCount = 0;
    int destination_writtenCount = 0;
    while(blockCount-- > 0) {
        if(blockCount == 0) {
            inputBlockSize = data.Length - data_writtenCount;
            if(inputBlockSize == 0) break;
        }
        destination_writtenCount += transformBlockCall(data: data.Slice(data_writtenCount, inputBlockSize)
            , destination: destination.Slice(destination_writtenCount));
        data_writtenCount += inputBlockSize;
    }
    return destination_writtenCount;
}


public static (RSAParameters keyPublic, RSAParameters keyPrivate) GenerateKeyPair(int keySize = 2048) {
    RSAParameters keyPriv;
    RSAParameters keyPub;
    using(var rsa = RSA.Create(keySize)) {
        keyPriv = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
        keyPub = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
    }
    return (keyPub, keyPriv);
}

#endregion Methods_Helper


}


public static class Program
{

static void Main() {

    var (keyPublic, keyPrivate) = RsaService.GenerateKeyPair();

    var encryptor = RsaService.Create(keyPublic);
    var decryptor = RsaService.Create(keyPrivate);
    string originalText = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        originalText += "ABC123456789";
    }
    byte[] inputData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originalText); // data random for test
    System.Console.WriteLine("inputData.Length: {0}", inputData.Length);

    var encryptedData = encryptor.Encrypt(inputData);

    System.Console.WriteLine("encryptedData.Length: {0}", encryptedData.Length);


    byte[] decryptedData = decryptor.Decrypt(encryptedData);
    string decryptedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData);

    System.Console.WriteLine("status: {0}", decryptedText == originalText);

}
}
```