# How to RSA Modulus & Exponent works in C# if both are in decimal format

Tags: c#, rsa

I'm working on RSA encryption and have my public key in C#. But i have my public key modulus and exponent in decimal format as below :

modulus:
18597082174523508716390621410767314599038866539779750637065684697259605002694360104971398651747704217448206242771805831180528356170981586469477958663193117845356353634469679095227815268434823260637917891539622982485837392495877800705071553435850492058570460745900129552907596604479063007676795998193064078987369363544131073880694736862904482385332020513837955197528182597410203652025183467149166026077910473816908590029574674997850683021938033561647681780168764842253700974777073181357779101690539999736174329578178742236883520017849893817175274405622018571899733008344137833140207194792223664500885734080606246950229

public exponent:
65537

How can i use above for RSA encryption in c#?

Comment: What is "decimal format"? A `string`? a `BigInteger`?

Comment: @xanatos its is a BigInteger

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# RSA encryption/decryption with transmission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128038/c-sharp-rsa-encryption-decryption-with-transmission)

Comment: RSA encrypting is `cipher = plain ** exponent (mod modulus);` In your case `BigInteger cipher = BigInteger.ModPow(plain, exponent, modulus);`

Comment: @GWigWam In the given example they have generated Modulus and exponent but in my case i have already been provided with modulus and exponent.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko In my case what would be value of Plain?

Comment: @chirag1707: `plain` is integer value, must be less than `modulus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
public static class BigIntegerExtensions
{
    public static byte[] ToByteArrayBigEndianUnsigned(this BigInteger bi, int minSize = 0)
    {
        byte[] bytes = bi.ToByteArray();

        int length;

        if (bytes[bytes.Length - 1] != 0)
        {
            if (minSize == 0 || minSize <= bytes.Length)
            {
                Array.Reverse(bytes);
                return bytes;
            }

            length = bytes.Length;
        }
        else
        {
            length = bytes.Length - 1;
        }

        var bytes2 = new byte[minSize == 0 ? length : Math.Max(minSize, length)];

        for (int i = 0, j = bytes2.Length - 1; i < length && j >= 0; i++, j--)
        {
            bytes2[j] = bytes[i];
        }

        return bytes2;
    }
}

var bi1 = BigInteger.Parse("18597082174523508716390621410767314599038866539779750637065684697259605002694360104971398651747704217448206242771805831180528356170981586469477958663193117845356353634469679095227815268434823260637917891539622982485837392495877800705071553435850492058570460745900129552907596604479063007676795998193064078987369363544131073880694736862904482385332020513837955197528182597410203652025183467149166026077910473816908590029574674997850683021938033561647681780168764842253700974777073181357779101690539999736174329578178742236883520017849893817175274405622018571899733008344137833140207194792223664500885734080606246950229");
var bi2 = BigInteger.Parse("65537");
var bytes1 = bi1.ToByteArrayBigEndianUnsigned();
var bytes2 = bi2.ToByteArrayBigEndianUnsigned();

var pars = new RSAParameters();
pars.Modulus = bytes1;
pars.Exponent = bytes2;
```

There are two differences about how `BigInteger.ToByteArray()` exports to `byte[]` and how `RsaParameters` expects its parameters: `BigInteger` is signed and little endian, so some `Modulus` have a 0 appended to make them positive (and for 1024 bits keys are 129 bytes long instead of 128) and the most significant digit is the last one, `RsaParameters` expects its parameters to be unsigned (so a 1024 bit key must be 128 bytes long) and big endian (so the most significant digit is the first one).

Note that importing the private key from `BigInteger` is even more complex :-)

Note 2: the `minSize` in `ToByteArrayBigEndianUnsigned()` is for importing private keys with `InvariantQ.Length < Exponent.Length / 2`. Ignore it.

Comment: BigInteger ToByteArray() is Little Endian.  RSAParameters values are Big Endian.  You need to Array.Reverse before returning it.  (You can't notice for 65537 since it's a palindrome in base 256)

Comment: @bartonjs Ah... Yes... You are right! :-) Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else finding this, we can use native built in support for this functionality now.
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23812

```cs
var bi1 = BigInteger.Parse("18597082174523508716390621410767314599038866539779750637065684697259605002694360104971398651747704217448206242771805831180528356170981586469477958663193117845356353634469679095227815268434823260637917891539622982485837392495877800705071553435850492058570460745900129552907596604479063007676795998193064078987369363544131073880694736862904482385332020513837955197528182597410203652025183467149166026077910473816908590029574674997850683021938033561647681780168764842253700974777073181357779101690539999736174329578178742236883520017849893817175274405622018571899733008344137833140207194792223664500885734080606246950229");
var bi2 = BigInteger.Parse("65537");
var bytes1 = bi1.ToByteArray(true, true); // isUnsigned: true, isBigEndian: true
var bytes2 = bi2.ToByteArray(true, true);

var pars = new RSAParameters();
pars.Modulus = bytes1;
pars.Exponent = bytes2;
```