# rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(privateKey, out _) is not supported in .net 2.0, can anyone please suggest an alternate way to Import custom private key

Tags: .net

Below is the code which I want to use to create token from custom private key.. Where I am getting error for rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(privateKey, out _) method which is not supported in 2.0 .net framework

```
        public string CreateToken(string _customerprivateKey, List<Claim> keypairs)
        {
            try
            {
                IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
                // var privateKey = privateKeybyteArr;

                byte[] privateKey = Convert.FromBase64String(_customerprivateKey);

                RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
                **rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(privateKey, out _); // not supported in 2.0 .net framework**

                var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
                    new RsaSecurityKey(rsa),
                    SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha512)
                {
                    CryptoProviderFactory = new CryptoProviderFactory { CacheSignatureProviders = false }
                };

                List<System.Security.Claims.Claim> _claims = new List<System.Security.Claims.Claim>();
                foreach (var item in keypairs)
                {
                    _claims.Add(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(item.Key, item.Value));
                }
                var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    claims: _claims,
                    signingCredentials: signingCredentials
                );

                string token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);
                return token;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have passed the privateKey in XML format to createToken method which resolved my my problem. Referred [C# RSA encryption/decryption with transmission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128038/c-sharp-rsa-encryption-decryption-with-transmission.).