# Public and Private Key as variables C#

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, bouncycastle, encryption-asymmetric

I'm writing a function where this function is receiving my public key as variable, and the value for this variable is the actually public key.  I need two different functions apps in Azure, to encrypt and decrypt. The keys must match, but the problem is, every time I call the API the public key is different, I can encrypt without problems. But when I have to decrypt it doesn't work. I am not able to use the same key pairs for these functions. Thats why Im trying to use the keys I generated before as variables.

**Example:**
`string publicKey = "MMMFisIDUDHfhHSANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAi7ZOKtc55v9NJuhQFR583BcFkcjflXNVMqC5/3b7t7v..."`

This is the method I'm using to encrypt:

`cipher.Init(true, publicKey);`

My keys are being generated using Bouncy Castle.

`RsaKeyPairGenerator g = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();`
`g.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), 2048));`
`AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = g.GenerateKeyPair();`

It worked normally with the code below:

```
        string plainText = "test data here";
        byte[] plainTextToByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

        //Generating Key Pair
        RsaKeyPairGenerator g = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
        g.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), 2048));
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = g.GenerateKeyPair();

        //Extracting the private key from pair
        RsaKeyParameters privateKey = (RsaKeyParameters)keyPair.Private;
        RsaKeyParameters publicKey = (RsaKeyParameters)keyPair.Public;

        //Encryption proccess
        IAsymmetricBlockCipher cipher = new OaepEncoding(new RsaEngine());
        cipher.Init(true, publicKey);
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.ProcessBlock(plainTextToByte, 0, plainTextToByte.Length);
        string encryptedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(cipherText);
        Console.WriteLine(encryptedText);

        //Decryption Process
        cipher.Init(false, privateKey);
        byte[] decryptedText = cipher.ProcessBlock(cipherText, 0 , cipherText.Length);
        string decryptedTextToString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedText);

        Console.WriteLine(decryptedTextToString);
        Console.ReadLine();`
```

I need the keys generated above as a variable to use in a function inside a console app.

But when I try pass the key as variable, I'm getting the error below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLSOL.png

I could do same procedure using core classes from C#, it was similar with the code below:

[C# RSA encryption/decryption with transmission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128038/c-sharp-rsa-encryption-decryption-with-transmission)

The same logic I follow for the example above is not working for me now. I am beginner into all this.
**Is there a way to do that?**

This is the piece code I'm using to get the error on the screenshot. The keys were generated with the code I posted on the original post.

```
    string plainText = "test here";
    byte[] plainTextToByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

    string publicKey = "MIIBIjANBgk...DAQAB";

    IAsymmetricBlockCipher cipher = new OaepEncoding(new RsaEngine());
    cipher.Init(true, publicKey);
    byte[] cipherText = cipher.ProcessBlock(plainTextToByte, 0, plainTextToByte.Length);
    string encryptedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(cipherText);
    Console.WriteLine(encryptedText);

    return new OkObjectResult(encryptedText);`
```

Att.

Comment: Use PEM keys or Base64 encoded DER keys. These are strings. BC and C# (the latter not in all versions) support import/export.

Comment: It didn't work either. I might be doing something wrong. I tried a different approach where I created two different functions: one for encrypt and for decrypt. But its still not working since I got different keys every time I request it from the API.

Comment: Don't you want to export the public key generated with `g.GenerateKeyPair()` as a string and import this key again later and use it in `cipher.Init(true, publicKey)`? A Base64 encoded DER key does not change during import/export. Maybe I misunderstand the question. See also [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I might be overthinking whole this process but I don't see how I can do that. Whenever I try with strings, I got the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLSOL.png

Comment: Screenshots are not very helpful. You should post how you generate the Base64 encoded DER key from `g.GenerateKeyPair()` (or whatever encoding you use) and how you later turn it into an `RsaKeyParameters` object that can be passed to `cipher.Init(true, publicKey)`.

Comment: Once again: Where does `MIIBIjANBgk...DAQAB` come from? I don't see anywhere in the code how you get this string!

Comment: My Public Key Generator:

           `RsaKeyPairGenerator g = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
            g.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), 2048));
            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = g.GenerateKeyPair();
            RsaKeyParameters publicKey = (RsaKeyParameters)keyPair.Public;
            TextWriter tw = new StringWriter();
            PemWriter pw = new PemWriter(tw);
            pw.WriteObject(publicKey);
            pw.Writer.Flush();
            string printPublicKey = tw.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(printPublicKey);`

Comment: I need two different functions apps in Azure, to encrypt and decrypt. The keys must match, but the problem is, every time I call the API the public key is different, I can encrypt without problems. But when I have to decrypt it doesn't work. I am not able to use the same key pairs for these functions. Thats why Im trying to use the keys I generated before as variables. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite clear what the problem is. But based on the last snippet posted in the question, you are trying to import a public key. And according to your penultimate comment, it is a PEM encoded public key in X.509/SPKI format exported with a `PemWriter`:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIB...
...AQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Such a key can be imported and used in `Cipher#Init()` as follows (let `publicKeyPem` be the exported PEM key):

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
...
PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(new StringReader(publicKeyPem));
RsaKeyParameters publicKeyReloaded = (RsaKeyParameters)pemReader.ReadObject();
...
cipher.Init(true, publicKeyReloaded);
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance @Topaco, now I'm able to encrypt the data I want to. I will now follow the same logic for decrypting the data. I'll use the output of this function to encrypt and set into a variable and see what happens. Cheers! :)